# macOS app local notification doesn't show app icon?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

I've already added AppIcon.appiconset Icon Files in info.plist, also no xcassets warnings. If I understand correctly, the app should show AppIcon if I set IconFiles in info.plist and AppIcons in General right?

[image: Default app icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug in Xcode 13. Restarting my Mac solved the problem.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682648